# @react-google-maps/api can't print polygon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, download, react-google-maps-api

why i can't print the polygon when i using library @react-google-maps/api ?
when i make it as pdf the data goes in, but when i click dowload which code like this

```
const print =() => {
     var printContents = document.getElementById('canvas').innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

the google maps data not generated, the polygon missing.

Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Google Maps API is modifying the display with CSS for print.

[image]
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#print